# Creating Apex Class dynamically

Tags: class, apex-code, frombodyattribute

I have created Apex Trigger through passing this parameters and link:

```
  { 
  "Name" : "COTriggerEmp11", 
 "TableEnumOrId" : "employee__c",
  "Body" : "trigger COTriggerEmp11 on employee__c (before insert) {system.debug('Record Inserted');}"
}

 URL  :https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger
```

Now I want to create Apex Trigger same way...
   Which parameters I need to pass And what should I write in Body section.
   I am have referred this doc also :
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried by my own, got this solution and it is working fine.
To create an Apex class dynamically do the following:

```
{ 
    "Name": "aaTest1",
    "Body": "public class aaTest1{}"
}
```

This will generate the class ID automatically.
Now if you want to delete that class, you should pass that ID like this:

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/ApexClass/[Your Class ID]
```

Maybe this will help somebody who is stuck like I was..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to take this further and generate a larger Apex class via automation.  Doing so I found some special considerations due to use of JSON to pass the code that I wanted to note to help others potentially if they want to do same.

First of all I had to escape use of backslashes (replace occurrences of `\` with `\\`).  In fact, because I was coding in Apex (creating a Salesforce class from within Salesforce), I had to even escape them in my source code that was massaging the class code so my apex statement became...

```
string bodystring = batchCode.replace('\\','\\\\');
```

And then I also needed to escape the newline characters in the code (replace occurrences of `\n` with `\\n`).

Other source code I was working with had tab characters in it and those caused issues with JSON deserialization. So added `mycode.replace('\t',' ')` to clean them out of the code.

With those adjustments to my code I was able to create Apex classes via automation.